# Bug in tablet/phone, css 100vh height doesn't work

Tags: html, css

http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20150924-m0uf-62kb

I don't know why this is white.

```
html{
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin:10px;
  position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;
}
```

I tried different options,

`height:100%`

but they don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The viewport units with `vh` are options in css which aren't supported by all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

If you want to use only css percentage height you should add to the parent element  `height: 100%` and now you can set the elements inside (for example the `body`) to `min-height: 100%`:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Optionally you can style your elements with javascript additionally (at the bottom of your html page):

```
function sizeFullHeight() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.minHeight = window.innerHeight+'px';
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.minHeight = window.innerHeight+'px';
}

sizeFullHeight();
window.onresize = sizeFullHeight;
```

or with jquery:

```
function sizeFullHeight() {
    $('html').css("min-height",$(window).height());
    $('body').css("min-height",$(window).height());
}
$(document).ready(sizeFullHeight);
$(window).resize(sizeFullHeight);
```